I can expoet data from yohost Seo to rank math
When I tried to install Rank Math, I should see an option to import Yoast SEO data. However, during my installation process, that option isn't available. I'm not sure why this is happening. How can I export my Yoast SEO data to Rank math
First, I noticed that Yoast SEO wasn't working correctly in my website's article editor. I decided to install Rank Math. In videos I watched, there was an option to import data from Yoast SEO to Rank Math; however, this option isn't available in my installation process. I'm hesitant to proceed with the installation because I'm unsure how to verify whether the data has been imported or not.
